# What's a simple way to make a view's layout_width="match_parent" and make the height equal to its width?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like a view styled similar to the album art in the Rdio app ([img](http://www.androidappmobile.com/wp-content/uploads/images/21/android-quick-app-rd_129371664078.png))

I don't know how I should be going about this. I want to load a bitmap into the view, if that affects the solution at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case (where the control has the full width of the device) you can always just use `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();` to get the width and then manually set the height.

If you're not using the full display width then you'll probably need to override `onMeasure` in the View class and set the height to match the width in there, perhaps like this:

```
@Override protected void onMeasure( int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec )
{
    viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize( widthMeasureSpec );
    viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize( heightMeasureSpec );

    if(viewWidth != 0) viewHeight = viewWidth;
    setMeasuredDimension( viewWidth, viewHeight );
}
```

Comment: I used ImageView's `setMinimumHeight();` method in combination with your `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();` to get it done. Thank you very much!